# auto resize subview from xib

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

In my app, the window.contentView size is 700*500, and I initialize a view, named view1, from xib, which size is 480*300, after I add the view1 as the subview of window.contentView, I need to automatically resize view1 to 700*500, I have set autoresizingMask but it doesn't work.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    self.rootViewController = [[TrendRootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TrendRootViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    NSView *view1 =  self.rootViewController.view;
    [self.contentView addSubview:view1];
    NSLog(@"view1 frame %@",NSStringFromRect(view1.frame));
}
```

view1 xib
[image]

my app:(The red view is view1)
[image]

it's weird that the frame of view1 is "view1 frame {{0, 0}, {480, 300}}", but as shown bellow, the view1 didn't at top-left position.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by changing the position of the arrow in the Origin box right above the resizing box in IB. Just click on the top left of the origin box and your view should appear on top left.

Answer (score 0):

> "it's weird that the frame of view1 is "view1 frame {{0, 0}, {480,
>   300}}", but as shown bellow, the view1 didn't at top-left position."

OS X is not iOS, and AppKit is not UIKit.

The default coordinate system in iOS for UIKit-based views is Upper-Left-Origin (ULO), while the default in OS X for AppKit-based views is a Lower-Left-Origin (LLO).

So it makes sense that the frame of the red view is `{{0, 0}, {480, 300}}`, as its origin is at `{0, 0}`, which is the lower-left corner of the window's `contentView`.

Unlike some `UIViewController`s in iOS, `NSViewController` does not automatically adjust the size of its view to fit the window's size. If you want the view's frame to match that of the window, you have a couple of different options.

One option is to set the frame of the view yourself before adding it as a subview to the window's `contentView`:

```
NSView *redView = self.rootViewController.view; // force view to load
[redView setFrame:NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, NSWidth(self.window.frame),
                                       NSHeight(self.window.frame))];
[self.window.contentView addSubview:redView];
```

Alternatively, in Interface Builder, you could add an `NSBox` that is the same size as the window's content view to the window. In IB, set the box's Title Position to `None`, Box Type to `Custom`, and Border Type to `None`. Set its "springs and struts" (autoresizing masks) to be identical to those of the view in your view1.xib (so that when you resize the window, the box resizes along with it). Then create an `IBOutlet` for the box, and instead of adding the view controller's `view` as a subview to the window's `contentView`, call `NSBox`'s `setContentView:` and pass the view controller's view:

```
[self.box setContentView:self.rootViewController.view];
```

As documented in `NSBox`'s [`setContentView:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBox_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBox/setContentView%3a) method, the view you pass in "…is resized to fit within the box’s current content area and the box is marked for redisplay." In other words, the box automatically handles resizing the view to the proper size for you.